# Ruby initialize

Tags: ruby, initialization

In the example below ([source](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/2/)),

```
class Greeter
  def initialize(name = "World")
    @name = name
  end
  def say_hi
    puts "Hi #{@name}!"
  end
  def say_bye
    puts "Bye #{@name}, come back soon."
  end
end
```

1. What is `def initialize(name = "World")` doing?
2. What is `@name = name` doing? Is it initializing the variable `name` and setting the initial value to be `name`?

I do not see any use of `"World"` anywhere further as I follow the example from the site (more code), hence my confusion on it's use.

> Now let’s create a greeter object and use it:
>
> ```
> greeter = Greeter.new("Pat")
> greeter.say_hi
> # => Hi Pat!
> greeter.say_bye
> # => Bye Pat, come back soon.
> ```

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions/253896#comment17104_253896

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > **1. What is `def initialize(name = "World")` doing?**

When you create a new instance of `Greeter`, **if** no argument is passed then `def initialize` sets the default `@name` attribute of your new instance to equal `"World"`.

> > **2. What is `@name = name` doing? Is it initializing the variable `name` and setting the initial value to be `name`?**

`@name` is an instance variable which other methods from the same class can see and use. In this case it takes the `name` parameter that is passed to the method. See *instance variables* for more information.

**Example**

In your example `greeter = Greeter.new("Pat")`, the argument is defined as`"Pat"` so the default argument of `"World"` is ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand the difference between instance variables like `@name` and local variables like `name`. They're not the same, but can be easily confused.

The initialize function is best explained as this:

```
# Define an initialize method with an argument called name that has
# a default value of "World"
def initialize(name = "World")
  # Assign the value of the name variable, which only exists in the
  # scope of this method, to the name instance variable which exists
  # for the lifespan of this Greeter object.
  @name = name
end
```

Instance variables are the backbone of Ruby's object oriented programming. They're the most convenient method to persist data between different method invocations.

To exercise the default behaviour you simply fail to specify what `name` should be:

```
greeter = Greeter.new
greeter.say_hi
```